# When using spring STOMP with the Rabbit broker relays, user queues stay around forever

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp

I have a `StompBrokerRelay` set up in spring boot with all the defaults connecting to a local rabbitmq with stomp plugin

```java
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

If I connect as user TestUser - I get the expected CONNECTED frame back:

```java
s = stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/test', () => {});
```

```
CONNECTED
server:RabbitMQ/3.12.4
session:session-BGUvC6LcEkqANzN6h_lpEQ
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.2
user-name:TestUser
```

A queue gets created in Rabbit called `test-user8bd7ef32-8b64-41bb-e198-4e91c869f359`.  It seems it uses a session id instead of the user name.  If I disconnect my websocket, the queue remains in rabbit forever.  If I reconnect as the same user with a new websocket connection, I get a new queue with a new session id appended, such as `test-user6ba34af7-f40b-aee4-5135-f80b2306570d`

I assume STOMP has to use the session id in the queue name instead of the user in case the same user has multiple sessions open.  It seems the `UserRegistry` keeps track of sessions per user.  This poses a couple of challenges:

If I want to reconnect, I get a new queue with a new session id, and any messages that were sent to the old queue in the mean time are stuck there forever.  I also never get to consume them on the new session.  On top of that, there seems to be no cleanup of these old abandoned queues.  They just sit in rabbit forever.

Is this intended by design?  Is there some kind of server-side configuration that would allow me to get these queues to be cleaned up?

For test purposes, I'm simply sending the user name as a query param on the WebSocket URL such as `/websocket?user=TestUser`.

I have an overridden handshake handler that uses that to determine the user:

```java
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").setHandshakeHandler(
            new DefaultHandshakeHandler() {

                @Override
                protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                        Map<String, Object> attributes) {
                    String user = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest().getParameter("user");
                    return new Principal() {

                        @Override
                        public String getName() {
                            return user;
                        }
                        
                    };
                }

        });
    }
```